# VBA Error 1004 - CopyPicture method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am using this code to save the worksheet range as the png file.....
I am usually able to generate up to 50 images (or 35) 0 doing loop through the data - but then it just gives the above error - VBA Error 1004 - **CopyPicture method of Range class failed**

```
Option Explicit

Sub biy_comara()
    Dim spath As String
    Dim rrng As Object, sht As Object
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("chart")
    spath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sht.Range("ao1").Value & ".png"
    Set rrng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:aj102")
    rrng.CopyPicture appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    
    With rrng.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(30, 30, 400, 400)
        .ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Height = rrng.Height
        .Width = rrng.Width
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.export Filename:=spath, filtername:="png"
        .Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

I wonder if anyone can help me with this? thanks a lot!)

Comment: What line does arise the error? Also, if you are looping, there is no loop in your code. Usually, if a loop works 35 times, but fails 1, maybe the problem is the data itself, not the code.

Comment: this macro is just called inside the other loop -- this line gets error -  rrng.CopyPicture appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture